# Problem related to vue-router, i can not exclude some words from path regex

Tags: regex, vue.js, vue-router, path-to-regexp

I have problem related to vue-router I need to exclude some group of words like: **word1, some-word2, word3...** from the router path

```
{ 
    path: '/:pageIdenfifier(?!word1|some-word2|word3), 
    name: 'SomePage', 
    component: () => import('@/views/index'), 
    props: true, 
}
```

but it doesn't work - https://paths.esm.dev/?p=AAMeJbiAwBIUTHbAdgHNgAGvAjgHhxDgd4DsAYC1AEYGfCB1eFujBYAiq5kBdgSY4KMICgAA&t=/word1#

Answer (score 2):

As alternative, you can use `beforeEnter` guard for this route, like:

```js
const blackList = ['word1','some-word2','word3']

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/:pageIdenfifier',
      name: 'SomePage',
      component: () => import('@/views/index'), 
      props: true,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        blackList.includes(to.params.pageIdenfifier)
          ? next('/route-in-case-of-true')
          : next();
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

In `beforeEnter` just check if `pageIdenfifier` match some value from `blackList`, in case of `true` you should provide another route or 404 page

Comment: I know about 'beforeEnter' alternative, and I used to 'beforeEnter' but it is not that what I need but anyway thank you

Answer (score -1):

I only skimmed the documentation of [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0), which is used by vue-router, but I have two guesses:

The negative look ahead in a regular expression requires
round brackets, but the syntax of path-to-regexp also does, so try adding another set:

```
path: '/:pageIdenfifier((?!word1|some-word2|word3))',
```

Using this syntax, also "gets rid of" the [default regular expression](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#custom-match-parameters), so you may need to add that back in:

```
path: '/:pageIdenfifier((?!word1|some-word2|word3)[^\\/]+)',
```

(BTW, the string in your code is also lacking a closing quote `'`. Maybe it's just that.)